# Where is this apache-error: fin|success error coming from?

Tags: apache-2.2

I get a bunch of these

```
apache-error: fin|success
```

errors in my apache error logs.

I cannot figure out which service or module is spitting out these messages.

It does not seem to affect anything. I am just curious where it's coming from. Does anyone know?

I am running a Rails apps with Passenger.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you provide any further details regarding the error log

Comment: Honestly, not really. It's just a standard apache error log, and every once in a while, I'll see a new line with "fin|success".. That's it. Nothing else on that line. No timestamp, nothing.

Comment: Check your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY! figured it out on accident. It's a message left by the PDF maker I am using -- princexml.